# How to convert a String with umlauts back to JSON

Tags: python, json, string, decode, encode

I have this JSON Python String:

```
linklist = str('
{
   "Download":{
   "Test": "http://www.test.org",
   u"K\xf6ter": "http://www.koeter.de"}
}'
)
```

I want to use:

```
myJson= json.loads(linklist)
```

But I get a problem because there is an German umlaut in the JSON String

What ist the best way to encode/decode this string so the string ist converted to a valid JSON Object with simplejson

**Hey guys here is what I wanted to do in my code:**

JSON: links.json

```
{
 "Download":{
    "Link1ä":"http://www.link1.de/test",
    "Link2ö":"http://www.link2.de/test/cool",
    "Link3ü":"http://www.link3.de/test/foo/bar",
    "Link4ü":{"Link5ü":"http://www.link5.de/test"}
}
}
```

Python File:

```
linksFile = open('links.json', 'r')
linksList = json.load(linksFile)
```

In this **linksList** I want to search for test and replace it to i.e myTest

How can I replace in this JSON-Object **linksList** all Strings -> test -> myTest

**Thank you very much for helping**. I tried following to make replacements on the JSON object and have no problems with umlauts:

```
linksFile = open('links.json', 'r')
linksList = json.load(linksFile)
dump = json.dumps(linksList)
linksList = json.loads(dump.replace('toReplace', 'replacement'))
```

Comment: How did you get at this string?

Comment: @delnan Yes his string is not quite right, but (utf-8 json) > `json.loads` > `json.dumps` and (python list containing UTF-8 str) > `json.dumps` > `json.loads` are not, at least from looking at console output, symmetrical operations.  Nor does due Google diligence, at least for me, produce an explanation.  Both operations appear to give you a `unicode`/UTF-16 representation, not UTF-8.  Holds true using explicit `encoding='utf-8'` with `dumps` and `loads` too.

Answer (score 1):

If that string was **Köter** then you problem is in encoding, not the json (de)serialization. Looks like you are using cp1250.

Try specifying the encoding explicitly (the default one is UTF-8 which is obviously not your case):

```
myJson = json.loads(linklist, 'cp1250')
```

Comment: There's nothing that really suggests he's using cp1250 here.  The key in his JSON string is prefixed with a `u`, suggesting wherever he's sourced this string from has already correctly decoded or originally sourced the ö to or as `unicode`.  Without more information (an error/callstack or the original code where this is coming from), there's no way to tell what the source encoding is, much less if encoding is causing the problem at all.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice the u'' prefix. I deduced the codepage from that fact that lennykey said it was an umlaut, and '\xf6' stands for **ö** in cp1250.

Comment: The JSON literal is non-unicode though (since there's no u'' prefix) unless Python 3 is used, of course. Thus that '\xf6' stands for a single byte and it cannot be valid for a two-byte encoding such as UTF-16 (either little or big endian). Anyway, that u" stuff renders the whole JSON string invalid regardless of the encoding.

Comment: Sorry, you are right on that one.  I was looking at the output from `dumps` and `loads`, which do give the UTF-16 representation.  Must be `JSONDecode` or something doing that, because I can't find another way to get that representation out of python.